# “Close” or “delete” own question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, best-practice, delete

After having [asked this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423485/how-to-adhere-to-copyright-when-using-protected-content-w3c-document-license) I realized that it would better be suited on a different site.
In that case, should I delete the question or vote to close?
Is there something like a best practice?

Comment: I think it's better to delete it since it is off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off-topic questions with zero votes here can be deleted. If not, they may be [deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244) based on the following conditions:

- The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/168244) closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no positively scored or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days. (`RemoveAbandonedClosed`)
- The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/168244) unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score that are at least 30 days old. (`RemoveDeadQuestions`)

Other conditions may also apply.